# Google Cloud SQL connection in NodeJS app (Express) --> Error: connect ENOENT

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS app on Google Cloud services and getting the following error hen I try to call a database query using Postman through localhost/8080, which is where my server is listening: `connect ENOENT /cloudsql/<MY_CONNECTION_NAME>`. Here's my database connection file, `config.js`:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const {
  DB_PASS,
  DB_USER,
  DB_NAME,
} = process.env;

const config = {
  user: DB_USER,
  password: DB_PASS,
  database: DB_NAME,
  socketPath: `/cloudsql/${process.env.CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}`,
};

const connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

// create connection
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`Connected to database ${DB_NAME}`);
});

module.exports.connection = connection;
```

I know that Google recommends using a pool to connect, but I'm afraid that doing that will require me rewriting all my database queries, and I'm on a tight deadline.

I've been able to successfully shell into the database with MYSQL using the terminal.

Comment: do you have public IP enabled in your CloudSQL instance? Are you using flexible or standard App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Connecting to App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) page. In particular, here are some things you should check if the socket isn't present:

1. For GAE Flex, make sure you have the following in your `app.yaml`:

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
```

2. Ensure the SQL Admin API is enabled and make sure you have the correct IAM permissions (`Cloud SQL Client1 or higher) on your service account (`service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com`). If between projects, make sure you have the
3. Make sure you are spelling  `<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>` correctly. It should be in the format `<PROJECT>:<REGION>:<INSTANCE>` - you can copy it exactly from the "Instance Details" page for your instance.

Additionally, using a connection pool will have no effect on your queries. Using a pool only means that when you "open" a connection, it is actually reusing an existing connection, and when you "close" a connection it puts it back in the pool for your application to use elsewhere. The queries you perform using the pool should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

this is happen if you are using flex as env in `app.yaml` to run without errors remove the `env:flex` from your `app.yaml`,
your app.yaml need to look like this
[app.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5hES.png)

and you will successfully connected to the cloud sql without causing errors
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIzjL.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.